# taking safe input from url and making my input hacking safe

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, request.querystring

I have the following method in my php CRUD class:

```
//secure search method
    function secureInput($ary = array()){
        $this->connect();
        $securedArray = array();
        //print_r($ary);
        foreach($ary as $val){
            //echo($val.'<br />');
            $val = str_replace("'","",$val);
            $val = str_replace("#","",$val);
            $val = str_replace("~","",$val);
            $val = str_replace("!","",$val);
            $val = str_replace("%","",$val);
            $val = str_replace("*","",$val);    
            $val = str_replace("drop","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("show","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("insert","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("create","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("update","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("select","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace('"',"",$val);
            $val = str_replace("+","",$val);
            $val = str_replace(";","",$val);
            $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
            $securedArray[] = $val;
            }
            return $securedArray;
        }
```

I want to use the following code to take input and return clean input (hacking xss proof input) and then use it for my database queries like insert update and retrieve etc

```
require_once('classes/classes.php'); 
$crud = new CRUD();
$ar = array("Shah Hussai#n","shahhus';sai;'n3#05@xyz.com","",234);
$name = "";$email = "";$empty ="";$int = "";
$ary = $crud->secureInput($ar); 
if(!isset($ary[0]) || empty($ary[0])){
    echo("Please provide your name<br />");
    }
else{
    //update variables here
    $name = $ary[0];
    $email = $ary[1];
    $empty = $ary[2];
    $int = $ary[3];
    }//if
echo $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl(name,email...) values($name,$email,$empty,$int)";
```

Now i am not sure either this will protect my code from hackers Cross Scripting and sql injection attempts? or i should do something else for taking input safely?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To protect SQL Injections it will be best to use [Prepared Statement](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).Provided link will help you in the case.
For other risks it is better for you to be specific to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

yo can use this class

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8291-PHP-Check-request-values-to-detect-hacking-attempts.html

it easy for use

be successfull